# How to Copy and Resize Image in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, image, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have used the code from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/552141/Csharp-Image-resize-convert-and-save to resize images programmatically. However, that project uses the `System.Drawing` libraries, which are not available to Windows 10 applications.

I have tried using the `BitmapImage` class from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` instead, but it does not seem to offer the functionality that was found in `System.Drawing`..

Has anyone had any luck being able to resize (scale down) images in Windows 10? My application will be processing images from multiple sources, in different formats/sizes, and I am trying to resize the actual images to save space, rather than just letting the application size it to fit the `Image` in which it is being displayed.

**EDIT**

I have modified the code from the above mentioned link, and have a hack which works for my specific need. Here it is:

```
public static BitmapImage ResizedImage(BitmapImage sourceImage, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var origHeight = sourceImage.PixelHeight;
    var origWidth = sourceImage.PixelWidth;
    var ratioX = maxWidth/(float) origWidth;
    var ratioY = maxHeight/(float) origHeight;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var newHeight = (int) (origHeight * ratio);
    var newWidth = (int) (origWidth * ratio);

    sourceImage.DecodePixelWidth = newWidth;
    sourceImage.DecodePixelHeight = newHeight;

    return sourceImage;
}
```

This way seems to work, but ideally rather than modifying the original `BitmapImage`, I would like to create a new/copy of it to modify and return instead.

Here is a shot of it in action:
[image: screenshot of resized image]

Comment: Misleading title, OP. You have a way of resizing the image, what you really want to do is create a copy of the original image, resize the copy, then return the copy.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I posted the question before the edit. The edit added the code for resizing the original image. I would have posted it as an answer, but it hasn't been long enough yet. But I do like the new title. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to just create a constant of the image? Or a private property you can just reference the original copy of the image and use the same function?

Comment: Since I don't need to keep the original image data intact, it is ok the way it is now. I am just thinking for future generalization, I may want to return a copy of the original `BitmapImage` rather than modifying the original.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I may want to return a copy of the original `BitmapImage` rather than modifying the original.

There is no good method to directly copy a `BitmapImage`, but we can reuse `StorageFile` for several times.

If you just want to select a picture, show it and in the meanwhile show the re-sized picture of original one, you can pass the `StorageFile` as parameter like this:

```
public static async Task<BitmapImage> ResizedImage(StorageFile ImageFile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    IRandomAccessStream inputstream = await ImageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    BitmapImage sourceImage = new BitmapImage();
    sourceImage.SetSource(inputstream);
    var origHeight = sourceImage.PixelHeight;
    var origWidth = sourceImage.PixelWidth;
    var ratioX = maxWidth / (float)origWidth;
    var ratioY = maxHeight / (float)origHeight;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var newHeight = (int)(origHeight * ratio);
    var newWidth = (int)(origWidth * ratio);

    sourceImage.DecodePixelWidth = newWidth;
    sourceImage.DecodePixelHeight = newHeight;

    return sourceImage;
}
```

In this scenario you just need to call this task and show the re-sized image like this:

```
smallImage.Source = await ResizedImage(file, 250, 250);
```

If you want to keep the `BitmapImage` parameter due to some reasons (like the sourceImage might be a modified bitmap but not directly loaded from file), and you want to re-size this new picture to another one, you will need to save the re-sized picture as a file at first, then open this file and re-size it again.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you Grace. Is there a way to get the `BitmapImage` or the `IRandomAccessStream` into a `WriteableBitmap` or `RenderTargetBitmap` for encoding into a base64 string? I am able to do the `StorageFile` directly, but since the resized image is not a `StorageFile`, I need to get it back into a different data type for encoding.

Comment: I ended up changing the whole process to using a `WriteableBitmap` instead of a `BitmapImage` so that I have the image in the necessary format for encoding to base64. I still have to create a `BitmapImage` inside the `ResizedImage` function to get the original dimensions, but at least it works :)

Comment: @dubstylee, you are doing it in the right way, I can't find way to convert `BitmapImage` to 64base string. To get `IRandomAccessStream` to `WriteableBitmap`, you can use `BitmapDecoder`, but I think you have already know this.