# Ram usage of BitmapImage in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, ram, bitmapimage

In order to learn how develop on C# and Visual Studio i made an offline UWP application to read Comic/Manga stored in my Windows-based tablet.
One of the main steps was take the relative directory of each image in one episode and create a BitmapImage of eachone to load them to the FLipView.

Currently i'm doing it this way:

```
foreach (String value in ImageDirectory)
{                 
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync((value));
    IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    image = new BitmapImage();
    await image.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);  
    images.Add(image); //images is a <List> of BitmapImage
 }
```

In the most extreme case i have, with 124 images (50,1 Mb on disc) when loaded they use about 860 Mb of Ram which seems excesive.
I know that load all the images as one is not the most efficent approach, where a more on-demad solution would be better, but finally my questions is:

Is there a better (that uses less ram) way to load the images?

Comment: What is the source image type?  Are the jpegs, pngs, or what?

Comment: By default, **FlipView does support virtualization**. FlipView is a [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR242803)-derived controls and its [ItemsPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) is [VirtualizingStackPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel) which is a virtualizing panel, so it supports UI virtualization. For more, please see [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7c6d0cdb-63c4-4f25-b2ea-f4f0cacb730d).

Comment: To reduce the ram usage, please make sure you don't change FlipView's ItemsPanel (if change, please still use a virtualizing panel). Then you can 
try to combine with data virtualization to see if it helps. For more please see [ListView and GridView data virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i know my approach is not very efficient, and that i should use virtualization, but i did this a a learning project and so far i'm happy with the results, to read manga in the train is better than the apps of the store and i don't have any issue with the 2gb of ram of my tablet.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, you are right. `FlipView` does use the legacy `VirtualizingStackPanel` which only renders a few items. I am not sure if the ListView & GridView data virtualization technique can be applied here though as it might be part of the `ItemsStackPanel`/`ItemsWrapGrid` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have in mind that images loaded in memory are not compressed like on your disk. They are handled as bitmaps (uncompressed)

if you want to see a preview from all images on your disk, a good approach is to resize your images in memory, like in [How to Copy and Resize Image in Windows 10 UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019595/how-to-copy-and-resize-image-in-windows-10-uwp), and load the full image on demand.

Comment: Sounds like a fair answer, playing with the windows Photo app, i can see it also uses quite a bit of ram (even if is not a completely fair comparison).
Now I think i can sleep at ease.