# How can I set BasicProperties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties#Windows_Storage_FileProperties_BasicProperties_SavePropertiesAsync) explains pretty well how I can read a files basic properties. But what if I want to change those? For example, let's say I have an image file that has been created today and is 200x400 big. I want my program to change the creation day to the first of May 2019 and the size to 200x500. Now obviously the image isn't used to have this size. Do I need to stretch it first? Or will it just have a transparent/white strip on one/both sides?

Edit:

I tried doing this on my file:

```
                Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ImageProperties imageProperties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

                imageProperties.Height = "900";
```

But Height is protected, so I can only get it but not set it.

Comment: the program 'convert' might help

Comment: Have you tried it?  The image file format probably contains intrinsic information that maintains the size - would changing the Windows file properties have any effect on that?

Comment: What kind of “image file”? can you not open it in an editor like Gimp and resize it there? That has both options of ‘stretching’ the image and adding blank rectangles.

Comment: @DourHighArch Sure thing, but I want to do it inside of my app. I have edited something that I tried out meanwhile.

Comment: @BJMyers Well I first need to find a way how to actually change the windows file properties. See my edit why I can't do that.

Comment: Well there's your answer - Windows won't let you change the height/width of the image because they are defined by the image data.  You can't change the *content* of the file by changing the *properties* of the file.

Answer (score 0):

BJ Myers is right. You cannot directly set the height/width of the image from properties of your file.

You can only get this info from raw data. To change your image, you have to use image related API to resize. For example, you can refer to Grace's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019595/how-to-copy-and-resize-image-in-windows-10-uwp).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need create event handler in code behind or VM(view mode).
2. Compare the datetime.now with your set up date, subscribe it when you navigate to the page.
3. Once match the date, use visual states to change width and high of item.

PS; Not recommend do the changes in code behind. Try do the logic in VM.