# uwp c# Zoom Image without scrollview

Tags: uwp, scrollview, miracast

I test the [scenario 3 of the BasicMediaCasting sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting/cs/Scenario3_CustomPicker.xaml.cs). I share my image with:

```
await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(img.GetAsCastingSource());
```

Now my question is:

**Can I share a scrollView with the MiraCast?**

Or can I zoom my image without scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, only `MediaPlayer`, `Image` and `MediaElement` have the required `GetAsCastingSource` method, so you cannot create a casting source from a `ScrollView`. I understand that you would like to enable the user to zoom the picture while it is casted, but I think this is not possible unless the target device has this functionality by itself.

Comment: Sorry for bad news. If you are okay with the answer, you can accept it to mark the question as closed.

Comment: Can i transform the Image that it looks like a Zoom? I found this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/scaling-an-image-using-uwp-with-xaml-and-c-sharp/ May this work?

Comment: The approach you linked works only for display on the Page (in XAML). To be able to scale it for casting, you would have to modify the image itself in memory. Example of scaling can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019595/how-to-copy-and-resize-image-in-windows-10-uwp . When you generate a modified `BitmapImage`, you can use it as the source of `Image` and then cast it.