# How to resize Mapicons in UWP component

Tags: uwp

I'm working on a UWP app.

I need to resize a MapIcon in a map, according with the screen size.

The icon is very small on large screen.

This is part of the code where

...

Dim icon_uri = "ms-appx:///Assets/my_position.png"

Dim my_position_icon As New MapIcon() = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(New Uri(icon_uri))

....

The icon appears correctly but I need to resize it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How to resize Mapicons in UWP component

The size of [`Mapicon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-a-pushpin) bases on the source image size, And the Image property supports a maximum image size of 2048×2048 pixels. So, please use the big size image to replace current one.

Comment: Thanks, but probably I've been not clear. If I use a large image (2048×2048), the mMpicon appears very large on a small screen and normal or small on a very large screen.

So I want to resize programmaticaly the image before to assign it to the Mapicon.

I've found this discussion, but it do not apply to the Mapicon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019595/how-to-copy-and-resize-image-in-windows-10-uwp